# Android camera api v 2 FPS too slow

Tags: performance, android-camera, frame-rate

I test on camera api v1 and then on api v2 and result dramatically diferent the speed in camera api v1 is 12-15 fps(NV21) per second in other hand v2 gives only 4-5 frames(YUV_420_888)  with same resolution 640x480. I thought it should be faster...Why this happen and is it possible to fix?